# Javascript Array not being filled properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some trouble getting an array to be filled properly. I'm attempting to get a deck of cards to be loaded into an array and then shuffled which does work fine initially, however, after I do a check to see if there are enough cards left, the array does not load properly and everything more or less breaks.

Here's the relevant code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var deck = {
    //base deck before shuffle
    baseDeck: ['d02', 'd03', 'd04', 'd05', 'd06', 'd07', 'd08', 'd09', 'd10', 'd11', 'd12', 'd13', 'd14', 'h02', 'h03', 'h04', 'h05', 'h06', 'h07', 'h08', 'h09', 'h10', 'h11', 'h12', 'h13', 'h14', 'c02', 'c03', 'c04', 'c05', 'c06', 'c07', 'c08', 'c09', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 's02', 's03', 's04', 's05', 's06', 's07', 's08', 's09', 's10', 's11', 's12', 's13', 's14'],
    //Deck Shoe 
    shoe: [],

    //pull deck #, return to shoe 
    shuffleDeck: function () {
        this.shoe.length = 0;
        this.shoe = this.baseDeck;

        for (i = 0; i < this.shoe.length; i++) {
            var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
            var currentPlace = this.shoe[i];
            this.shoe[i] = this.shoe[randomPlace];
            this.shoe[randomPlace] = currentPlace;
        }
        }


}

var cardRetrieval = {

    //return card vals
    getCard: function (curHand) {
        var q = curHand.push(deck.shoe.shift());
        this.checkValue(curHand);
        showCards(curHand, q);
        if (deck.shoe.length <= 40) {
            deck.shuffleDeck();
            }
    }
```

Everything works fine until the if statement at the bottom that checks if there are 40+ cards in the shoe array. But when it attempts to shuffle the deck again, it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is with this:

```
this.shoe.length = 0;
this.shoe = this.baseDeck;
```

You're not making a *copy* of the `baseDeck` into the `shoe`. Instead you're overwriting the reference to the empty Array you created for `shoe`, and you're replacing it with a reference to the same Array that `baseDeck` references.

So it works the first time you shuffle, because `this.shoe.length = 0` is not yet affecting the `baseDeck`. But when you shuffle the second time, you're destroying the `baseDeck`. (Basically, with that first shuffle, you were using the `baseDeck` instead of a copy of it.)

Change it to this:

```
this.shoe.length = 0;
this.shoe = this.baseDeck.slice(0);
```

This will make a clean copy of `baseDeck` that is referenced by `shoe` each time.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I really appreciate the assistance! Long coding hours make for easy mistakes ;-).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your random number, 1) it will never be `0` - the first card in the deck, and 2) it may exceed the array size.
Use this instead:

```
var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.shoe.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the actual shuffleDeck function isn't loading properly when deck.shoe.length<=40?

Comment: Actually this doesn't produce a perfectly random shuffle - you should only shuffle the card with one of the cards that you have already shuffled. `var randomPlace = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));`